# Playing with dijit/form/select into content pane from somewhere by programmatically

Tags: select, dojo

Hi I am not sure where I went wrong with codes, when inserting the select form into content pane  named as "center 1". All the codes are working when codes for select are masked with comment until I removed the comment. it does not work.

[See my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clementyap/AxVcq/24/)

And see my select codes:-

```
var select_Card = new Select
                (
                    {   
                        options:[
                                    {label:"Mk7ABC Card", value:"testdata1970_05", selected:false},
                                    {label:"Mk7CBC Card", value:"testdata1970_10", selected:true},
                                    {label:"Mk10DC Card", value:"testdata2060_03", selected:false},
                                    {label:"Mk6BC Card", value:"dbProdigy", selected:false},
                                    {label:"Mk6NBC Card", value:"dbProdigy_MK6N", selected:false},
                                ],
                        style:{width:'250px'}
                    }, "id4"); 
                select_Card.startup();
```

Please advise. Thanks
Clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle, "target" is the id of a ContentPane dijit. So when you write this:

```
var select2 = new Select
    ({name: "select2",
      .....     
 }, "target");
```

You are telling the Select to make the ContentPane into a Select (technically, you tell it to hijack the ContentPane's div, which has id "target").

If you simply want to place the Select into the ContentPane, you can do:

```
var select2 = new Select
    ({name: "select2",
      .....     
 }).placeAt(registry.byId("target").containerNode);
```

There are a couple of other problems with your fiddle too:

**¤** Dependencies must be in the same order in require()'s array and callback:

```
require(["foo/Widget1", "foo/Widget2", "bar/Widget3"],
    function(Widget1, Widget2, Widget3) {....
```

not

```
require(["foo/Widget1", "bar/Widget3", "foo/Widget2"],
    function(Widget1, Widget2, Widget3) {....
```

(note that Javascript is case-sensitive too, so if you write "Select" in your code, you can't have "select" in your require parameters).

**¤** Remember to include the necessary CSS for your widgets:

```
<style type="text/css">
@import url("someUrl/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css");
@import url("someUrl/dojotoolkit/dojo/resources/dojo.css");
....
```

Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/AxVcq/30/

Comment: Hi Frode, Thank you very much for your helpful explanations. Now I understand better.